# EDAS upload fail: IEEEtran sidemargins_a4 error

Tags: margins, pdf

When uploading my paper to EDAS I get the following error: `The right margin is 1.422 cm on page(s) 4 (widths: 18.1; 18.1; 18.1; 18.1; 18.1; 8.9 cm), which is below the required margin of 1.6 cm for A4-sized paper.`

This is my header:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{+0.122cm}
\addtolength{\rightmargin}{+0.178cm}

\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}% requires -shell-escape
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\todo}[1]{{\textbf{\color{red} TODO: {#1}}}}
```

As you can see I added `\addtolength{\rightmargin}{+0.178cm}` in my attempt to fix the issue, but the error still occurs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using the `geometry` package and removing the `\addtolength` commands:

```
\usepackage[left=1.62cm,right=1.62cm,top=1.9cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: For me, changing `1.9cm` to `1.7cm` was enough, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these lines, it worked for me.

```
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTtoptextmargin}{2.4cm}
\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTbottomtextmargin}{4.6cm}
%\newcommand{\CLASSINPUToutersidemargin}{1.3cm}
%\newcommand{\CLASSINPUTinnersidemargin}{1.3cm}
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```